# Register Symfony Hydrators in Isolated Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, hydration

I have created several modular applications, which shared Bundles. One of these bundles responsible for handling all entity/repository related logic (lets call it MyBundle).

This MyBundle contains several custom hydrators. How can I register these hydrators in the bundle given that the doctrine configuration is contained in the specific applications and I don't wish to have to register the bundle hydrators in their config.yml files?

I've tried creating a CompilerPass in my bundle, then calling the addCustomHydrationMode on the doctrine orm configuration service but this doesn't work.

I also tried creating a 'HydrationManager' class, injecting the entity manager, then calling an addHydrator method on the manager in the compiler pass which in turn calls getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode(...) but this also did not work

Comment: I was trying to do the same and managed - in case it is of interest - to add my hydtrators in a kernel.request subscriber, injecting the doctrine.orm.entity_manager, from where you can call getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode(). Possibly a bit hacky, but it worked... until I found this answer and implemented as per ABM_Dan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a similar solution, and stumbled upon this example:
https://github.com/vivait/user-bundle/blob/master/src/Vivait/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineCompilerPass.php

```
<?php

namespace Vivait\UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class DoctrineCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * You can modify the container here before it is dumped to PHP code.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     *
     * @api
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $ormConfigDef = $container->getDefinition('doctrine.orm.configuration');
        $ormConfigDef->addMethodCall(
            'addCustomHydrationMode',
            ['UserCustomerHydrator', 'Vivait\UserBundle\Adapter\Hydrator\CustomerHydrator']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and then, of course, don't forget to add the compiler pass to the bundle class at the root of your bundle, as so: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html